# image loading problem in iPhone ? - from webservice

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
imgBiteSpot.clipsToBounds=YES; 
    NSData *imageData = [[[NSData alloc]init]autorelease];
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ObjBitSpot.StrImagePath]];
    if(imageData==0)
    {
        imgBiteSpot.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-not-found.gif"];
    }
    else {
        UIImage *imgs = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(88,88));
        [imgs drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 88.0, 88.0)];
        UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        imgBiteSpot.image=newImage;
        [imgs release];
    }
```

---

I have loaded an image to `imgBiteSpot`.
The image is loaded from the webservice. The problem is that it takes too much time (35 seconds to 1 minute).

If I remove image -> code / load, the reaction time is just 0.2 seconds.

What is the solution to reduce the time for the  image loading process?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using NSData's method `dataWithContentsOfURL:`, which loads the data synchronously from the server, and thus blocks on the thread until the image is received.

What you should do instead is load a blank or "loading" image into your UIImage, then use NSURLConnection to download the image asynchronously and display it when it's done. See the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference and the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) doc.

Answer (score 1):

I've written RemoteImage class to load images over the network asynchronously. It also takes care of freeing the memory when necessary. See this post: http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2009/11/remote-image-for-iphone/